# What are some data mining algoritms used in finance?

Tags: cryptography, data-mining

I want to test the applicability of [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) in the financial domain, as suggested in [Can homomorphic encryption be practical ?](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/405.pdf).

Now, I want to know what algorithms are used for financial cloud solutions, and if these methods can be improved by adding confidentiality of data. Namely, somebody wants both the cloud power for computation/storage and at the same time wants to feel his/her data are protected.

What are these algorithms used for financial cloud services and data mining that I should study ?

Comment: Homomorphic encryption is not practical at the moment. There is no need to try anything. Data mining algorithms are usually computationally intensive, so would be even worse.

Comment: Well, I have come across this paper Private Computation on encrypted genomic data by Lauter et.al https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/133.pdf, and I thought that it might be worth trying something similar for the financial sector. I have no expertise in data mining or algorithms used in financial computation. I want only to play with homomorphic encryption and see if I can do something worthy :)